# PHP and OOP: classes and unset()

Tags: php, oop

In theory, it is possible to create a class, an object which can not be removed by unset()?

Comment: What are you trying to solve wit this ? t sounds too much like you are looking for a *patch to a bugfix of a solution for a problem*. You should explain the problem, instead of asking for the patch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean `unset()` and object? Not only in theory. It's possible in practice. In fact, that part of why they invented the `__destruct()` magic method.

### EDIT by comments:

No, it's impossible to implement a class or an object which **cannot** be removed by `unset()`.

Comment: I'm asking, if it is possible to create a class or an object which can NOT be removed by unset()?

Comment: Oh, cannot. No that's not possible.